# User behaviour when user closes prompt and returns to video which is paused in the background?

Tags: user-expectation, video, prompt

**Scenario:** User is viewing a video. User can add annotation at desired time frame in the video. User can do this by tapping a button displayed on the video player. Tapping the button displayed user a prompt where user can add annotation. (Here it is important that the video is paused while the prompt is displayed to the user). After successfully adding the annotation, success message is displayed in form of toast message and the prompt closes.

**Problem statement:** What should be the user experience when user closes the annotation prompt?

1. Should the video start playing after closing the prompt so as to maintain the continuity and minimize clicks ?
2. Should the video remain in pause state and user can explicitly tap the play button to play the video from where it was paused ?

What is the user expecting from the application in this scenario?

Comment: Will the annotaion visible when he plays it again?

Comment: Yes, but not is form of prompt.
User will have visual indication whenever user is on the timeframe where the annotation is added.

Comment: Is it similar to youtube annotation?

Comment: Yes, Annotations added by the user would appear in form of markers on the seek bar

Comment: I got it, it is similar to, commenting on any part of the video. Is this what you are making?

Comment: Yes. However what would be the user expectation when a comment is successfully added?
Should the Video auto-play or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 2** will be more user friendly. Since the user is tapping to add annotation; which also means the user is pausing the video to add annotation. And per the rule of consistency - if the user has clicked (paused) to perform some action, he should again click (play) to resume the task.

Comment: I agree with @Dipak

Answer (score 0):

If I would be the user using your site, I prefer video should continue, when I click on button placed on successful message, saying "continue watching".

Or You can place a countdown message saying "*Your annotation is successfully created, now video will continue is 3 secs."* 
At that time in-order to let user edit his annotation, put a small link saying *click here to edit your annotaion.*

Hope this is helpful.